# How to reset <progress> to native appearance?

Tags: html, css

By default, `<progress>` tag looks like this on Firefox 50, macOS:

[image: Progress bar with no style on Firefox 50, macOS 10.11]

According to Developer Tools, `<progress>` element has following CSS rules applied by default:

```
progress {
    -moz-appearance: progressbar;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: threedhighlight #e6e6e6;
    -moz-border-left-colors: threedshadow #e6e6e6;
    -moz-border-right-colors: threedhighlight #e6e6e6;
    -moz-border-top-colors: threedshadow #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-color: -moz-use-text-color;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: -0.2em;
}
```

However, specifying these styles in user document leads to following fallback render:

[image: Progress bar with default style on Firefox 50, macOS 10.11]

I have tried to replace actual values with `initial`, still no luck. After playing with code a little I have figured out that applying any rule that affects `background`, `border` or `border-radius` makes progress bar look non-native.

Is there any way to make progress bar look native again using CSS? Solution that only works on recent versions of Firefox is totally acceptable.

Comment: Why are you styling it in the first place, if all you wanna do is have it native?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, I am injecting a progressbar from userscript, and target page already has progress bars reset, but not properly styled.